# Are PyTorch-trained models transferable between GPUs and TPUs?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, tpu

After using a GPU for some to train a PyTorch model, can I use the saved weights to continue training my model on a TPU?

Comment: Pytorch has no TPU support

Comment: @talonmies https://github.com/pytorch/xla

Answer (score 3):

> After using GPU for some time can I use the saved weights to train my model using TPU?

Yes, if you saved your GPU-trained model with, say

```py
    torch.save(model.save_dict(), 'model.pt')
```

you can load it again for use on a TPU (using https://github.com/pytorch/xla)  in a separate program run with

```py
    import torch_xla.utils.serialization as xser
    
    model.load_state_dict(xser.load('model.pt'))
```